# href link not working in ie 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, hyperlink, href

I just can't figure this out. The links below work absolutely fine in every browser except IE8. If you click on the  elements in IE8, the button disappears. If you click again where it was it reappears. But no amount of clicking will actually lead you to the href location. Can anybody explain to me why that might be? I've exhausted all of my thoughts and it still doesn't work. Many thanks for all your thoughts!

The html...

```
<div style="padding:0px 0px 30px 0px; clear: both;">
 <div style="width: 50%; display: block; float: left;">
  <a href="../index/features" class="big_button">Learn More</a>
 </div>
 <div style="width: 50%; display: block; float: left;">
  <a href="../index/signup" class="big_button">Get Started</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

...and the stylesheet...

```
 .big_button {
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #bbdaf7;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #79bbff
    ), color-stop(1, #378de5) );
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #79bbff 5%, #378de5 100%);
filter: progid : DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient (           
       startColorstr = '#79bbff', endColorstr = '#378de5' );
background-color: #79bbff;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
border: 1px solid #84bbf3;
display: inline-block;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 15px 45px;
text-decoration: none;
margin-left: 130px;
}

.big_button:hover {
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #378de5), color-stop(1, #79bbff) );
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #378de5 5%, #79bbff 100%);
 filter: progid : DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient (startColorstr = '#378de5', endColorstr = '#79bbff' );
 background-color: #378de5;
}

.big_button:active {
 position: relative;
 top: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Box shadows have problems with old versions of ie. Try this for a possible solution: http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/08/24/how-to-simulate-css3-box-shadow-in-ie7-8-without-javascript/

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. Unfortunately, even if I remove all references to box shadow in the css, the link still fails to work.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the 'filter:' part in your css, remove it, then it will work...

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. IE8 seems to have a problem with :active in css. So the following section of the stylesheet was causing issues:

```
.big_button:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

Current fix is to exclude the ':active' part of the css for the button as it's not essential. If anybody has any further information on why IE8 has issues with :active, I'd be interested to know about it.